# All rows selected on clicked

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I'm building a application in C# Winforms and using a `Datagridview`.

My problem is that when I click on a row, all rows are selected (without intention) and the application crashes (as the values inserted from the grid view selected row into labels are not intact (too many values...).

[image: The selection of all row done automatically]

The correct behavior I'm looking for is the selection of on row only.
I thought the problem might be in the `selectionMode` (I used the value "`RowHeaderSelect`"), but I changed it, and the problem persisted, so it isn't it.

Do you have an idea what might be the problem ??

---

Not relying on much code, really, but here it is:

```
private void dgvCustomersList_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            {
                customerFunctions ChoosenRow = new customerFunctions(); //empty
                DataGridViewRow dr = dgvCustomersList.SelectedRows[0];

                ChoosenRow.CfirstName = dr.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                ChoosenRow.ClastName = dr.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                ChoosenRow.Caddress = dr.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                ChoosenRow.CcreditNumber = int.Parse(dr.Cells[7].Value.ToString());
                ChoosenRow.CpersonalID = int.Parse(dr.Cells[5].Value.ToString()); 
            }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Comment: are you sure.. that is the only one event is executed?

Comment: try FullRowSelect and turn Multiselect to False. It looks like you might actually have the shift key stuck down